# Insert values into column when the two corresponding column values are not there

Tags: sql, sql-server, trino

I am creating a table with having user profiles associated with various events. Various variables of user profile change at various intervals ranging from daily to more than a year. Hence, once the user is associated with an event, his profile cannot change for that event.

While Inserting the values into the table through a Select query I need to ensure that there is no more than one record for one user ID and Event ID. How can I achieve this in the best optimal way? Thank You in advance.

e.g.

| event_id | user_id | age | gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1 | 24 | M |
| xyz | 5 | 31 | F |
| xyz | 5 | 31 | F |
| abc | 5 | 31 | F |

In the above table, the event_id = xyz and user_id = 5 has been entered twice. I need to ensure that the these type of value do not get inserted again from the query that I am retreiving the data.

Answer (score 0):

You would use a unique constraint or index:

```
alter table t add constraint unq_t_event_id_user_id
    unique (event_id, user_id);
```

Comment: This facility is not available in the database that I use

Comment: You have tagged the question with the database "sql-server" and SQL Server definitely supports this functionality.

Comment: Yes, I can use SQL server also but I will not prefer to use it as due to computational time it takes